# Trunc xml file using unix shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, bash-scripting

I need to select particular set of tags which contains a particular value inside the tag. 
For example, below is the source.XML file

```
<main tag>
<subTag1>1298</subTag1>
<subTag2>fg</subTag2>
<subTag3>34</subTag3>
</main tag>

<main tag>
<subTag1>1299</subTag1>
<subTag2>cfinfo</subTag2>
<subTag3>43</subTag3>
</main tag>

<main tag>
<subTag1>1300</subTag1>
<subTag2>BBcycle</subTag2>
<subTag3>55</subTag3>
</main tag>
```

I need to select all the contents of main tag values which has subTag1 value 1300  in to another XML.The expected output if subTag1 value is given as 1300 is below.(Result.XML)

```
<main tag>
<subTag1>1300</subTag1>
<subTag2>BBcycle</subTag2>
<subTag3>55</subTag3>
</main tag>
```

Like wise I need to select the main tag elements with set of subTag1 values.The expected output if subTag1 value is given as 1299 & 1300 is below.(Result.XML)

```
    <main tag>
    <subTag1>1299</subTag1>
    <subTag2>cfinfo</subTag2>
    <subTag3>43</subTag3>
    </main tag>

    <main tag>
    <subTag1>1300</subTag1>
    <subTag2>BBcycle</subTag2>
    <subTag3>55</subTag3>
    </main tag>
```

PS:There are no line break between tags , added for better understanding.
In real case scenario, There are lot of main tags and i have set of SubTag1 values to fetch that corresponding main tag blocks like the example above (to be created in a single resultant XML file). It would be appropriate if script user can give the set of subTag1 values for searching in SOURCE.XML.

I thought of using grep but it won't help in  selecting set of tags.
I need to do this using UNIX shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You need an XML parsing tool. [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php) is my favourite. After fixing up your invalid XML, we have

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//main_tag[subTag1 != 1300]' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root_tag>
  <main_tag>
    <subTag1>1300</subTag1>
    <subTag2>BBcycle</subTag2>
    <subTag3>55</subTag3>
  </main_tag>
</root_tag>
```

and

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//main_tag[subTag1 != 1300 and subTag1 != 1299]' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root_tag>
  <main_tag>
    <subTag1>1299</subTag1>
    <subTag2>cfinfo</subTag2>
    <subTag3>43</subTag3>
  </main_tag>
  <main_tag>
    <subTag1>1300</subTag1>
    <subTag2>BBcycle</subTag2>
    <subTag3>55</subTag3>
  </main_tag>
</root_tag>
```

I find [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) a helpful tutorial for xpath.

Comment: Yes this can be used but it needs installation which i don't have permission nor ask for permission

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
grep -A 3 -B 1 '<subTag1>1300</subTag1>' infile.xml > outfile.xml
```

`-A` select lines after context.
`-B` select lines before context

which outputs nicely

```
<main tag>
<subTag1>1300</subTag1>
<subTag2>BBcycle</subTag2>
<subTag3>55</subTag3>
</main tag>
```